# Updating Traffic Information OSRM

Tags: openstreetmap, geojson, osrm

I'm trying to utilize the experimental Traffic Updates feature on OSRM. I want to be able to supply updates to the duration/weight of an edge for nodes. Following the documentation, I created a .csv file with some updates called "updates.csv:

```
5491823813,5491823812,40,32.2
5491823812,53137860,3,3.2
```

I now build the osrm via the following commands:

```
osrm/osrm-backend:' + OSRM_DOCKER_VERSION + ' osrm-extract -p /opt/car.lua /data/' + pbfFileName + ' --generate-edge-lookup
```

```
osrm/osrm-backend:' + OSRM_DOCKER_VERSION + ' osrm-contract /data/' + osrmFileName + '--segment-speed-file.csv updates.csv --core 0.8 --level-cache true
```

where the docker version is `v5.21.0` and the osrmFileName is `bayArea.osrm` and the pbfFileName is `bayArea.pbf`.

This compiles fine, but when I feed it some sample gps coordinates/data for the `Route` service endpoint, the results are the same on the node edges for the duration weights. If I change the weight/speed values in the `updates.csv` and run this again, I get the exact same data generated by the `Route` or the `Match` service endpoint.

Any ideas on how to update the duration/weights of node edges?
Thank you!

Comment: Hi, not relevant to the post, but I wanted to understand what are durations/weights exactly? Is there any documentation around that? Not able to find much!

Answer (score 1):

Just if this is still relevant (I see people upvoting): there's a typo in the second command: `--segment-speed-file.csv`. Should use `--segment-speed-file <filename>` instead.